# Add new controller to existed module in zf3

Tags: php, zend-framework, zend-framework3

In Zend framework 3, I tried adding new controller "ArticleController" to a existed module City but failed. I post screen shot, my folder structure and module.config.php. Could you explain what the problem is? Incidentally, it worked when accessing http://0.0.0.0:7000/city

When accessing http://0.0.0.0:7000/article
[image]
[image]

Next, module\city\config\module.config.php codes are following:

```
<?php

namespace City;

use Zend\Router\Http\Segment;

return [
    'router' => [
        'routes' => [
            'city' => [
                'type'    => Segment::class,
                'options' => [
                    'route' => '/city[/:action[/:id]]',
                    'constraints' => [
                        'action' => '[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9_-]*',
                        'id'     => '[0-9]+',
                    ],
                    'defaults' => [
                        'controller' => Controller\CityController::class,
                        'action'     => 'index',
                    ],
                ],
            ],
            'article' => [
                'type'    => Segment::class,
                'options' => [
                    'route' => '/article[/:action[/:id]]',
                    'constraints' => [
                        'action' => '[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9_-]*',
                        'id'     => '[0-9]+',
                    ],
                    'defaults' => [
                        'controller' => Controller\ArticleController::class,
                        'action'     => 'index',
                    ],
                ],
            ],
        ],
    ],

    'view_manager' => [
        'template_path_stack' => [
            'city' => __DIR__ . '/../view',
        ],
    ],
];
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Error message is clear. Application doesn't know anything about your controller. Your module config has to have information about controllers under "controllers" key. Checkout [zend documentation](http://zendframework.github.io/zend-mvc/quick-start/#create-a-route), you'll see "controllers" key in config file.

Comment: Thank you for answering and sorry for being late to respond. I tried adding "controllers" to module.config.php but it failed.  Then, I found the solution. add values for article controller to key "factories" in City/src/Module.php. After finishing zend framework tutorial, I tried appending new controller. Tutorial applied "factories" so it didn't success. https://docs.zendframework.com/tutorials/getting-started/database-and-models/  Very sorry, Mehmet.

Comment: I assume your "controllers" config is like

 ["controllers" => ["factories" => ["MyController" => "MyControllerFactory"]]]

This is how "controllers" config how to be. You don't need factory if your controller doesn't have any dependency injection. So You will register it under "invokables" key.


 ["controllers" => ["invokables" => ["MyController"]]]